# neo4j query relationships between two sets and the two sets's size is 1000,any good idea?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

this is my clause

```
WITH ['141221199000689765','141221199000027194',....] AS x ,
     [ '141221199000636467','141221199000341572',....] AS y  
MATCH (a:person) 
WHERE a.id IN x 
MATCH (b:person) 
WHERE b.id IN y 
MATCH p=shortestPath((a)-[r:friend|neighbor|colleague|schoolmate*0..5]-(b)) RETURN p ;
```

The 1412211990006* is person's id, i'want to query  relationships between two groups of people by two sets of ids; There 200 million node of people and 1200million relationships between these nodes;the elapsed time is about 300second; I would appreciate any idea for optimizing,Thanks

Comment: Other than having an index in a.id (that you probably have), there's no much room for improvement here. You are performing 1M shortest path in 300s, that's ~3333 shortest path/s, which I think is not bad. The only thing I can think of is going the native extension way, instead of cypher.

Comment: thank you,but what' meaning of native extension of neo4j,you mean using neo4j HA?

Comment: No, I mean using the java api, that when [used right](https://maxdemarzi.com/2016/02/20/speeding-up-traversals/), can perform way better than cypher. To extend neo4j you can use [user defined procedures](https://neo4j.com/developer/procedures-functions/) or [unmanaged server extensions](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/)

Comment: I support the java api idea. In the meantime, have you tried slicing the query in smaller ones? If x size is 1000, try returning x and then executing 10 queries of 100-sized x each. It´s not actually intuitive, but in some cases it helped me avoid managing too many results at the same time.

Comment: Firstly,I'm so sorry for comment now,you'are right,I executing 10 queries of 100-sized x each in the concurrent programming

Comment: Extractly,i used 10 threads to query the relations of between 100-sized x and 1000- size y.